# How to design PI controller for a non-linear dynamic system?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, nonlinear-system, pi-controller

I have following dynamic system

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{1}{R_b\cdot C}\cdot v_C\cdot\alpha,
$$

where $v_C$ is the system state and output, $\alpha$ is the system input and $R_b, C$ are the system parameters. Due to the fact that the differential equation contains product of the state and input variable the system is non-linear. For the PI controller design it will be necessary to linearize the system in a given steady state operating point $(v_{C_{0}}, \alpha_0)$.

I have done this linearization

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\widetilde{v_C}}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{1}{R_b\cdot C}\left(v_{C_{0}}\cdot\widetilde{\alpha} + \widetilde{v_C}\cdot\alpha_0\right),
$$

where $\widetilde{\alpha}$ and $\widetilde{v_{C}}$ are the perturbations from the steady state operating point. This linearized model can be transformed into the Laplace domain

$$
 \frac{\widetilde{V}_C(s)}{\widetilde{\alpha}(s)} = -\frac{\frac{v_{C_{0}}}{R_b\cdot C}}{s + \frac{\alpha_0}{R_b\cdot C}}
$$

Here the PI controller design can be started but the transfer function is strongly dependent on the selection of the steady state operating point. My question is how to proceed in such situation? What steady state operating point shall I select for the PI controller design?

Comment: the operating point is whatever your goal is. one controller will not work to a desirable outcome for all cases. Hence gain scheduling.

Comment: just to elaborate, it is a bit of an art to picking a reasonable operating point and in 1D picking a midpoint of some operating range is not a bad idea. your controller will maybe work in a region of the operating point which is hopefully large enough to contain the operating range. If not, you need to use gain scheduling for example.

Comment: Will it work if you design the controller as $\alpha = R_{b} C k \left(\frac{x - x_{\text{op}}}{x}\right)$, where $x_{\text{op}}$ represents the operating point and $k$ is the desired exponential decay constant? If $x_{\text{op}} = 0$, can you set $\alpha$ to be a constant, $R_{b} C k$?