# Linearized model of a nonlinear dynamic system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, control-theory, linear-control

I have following dynamic system

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{1}{R_b\cdot C}\cdot v_C\cdot\alpha,
$$

where $v_C$ is the system state and output, $\alpha$ is the system input and $R_b, C$ are the system parameters. Due to the fact that the differential equation contains product of the state and input variable the system is nonlinear. I have linearized this model in a steady state operating point $(v_{C_{0_e}}, \alpha_{0_e})$.

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\widetilde{v_C}}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{1}{R_b\cdot C}\left(v_{C_{0_e}}\cdot\widetilde{\alpha} + \widetilde{v_C}\cdot\alpha_{0_e}\right),
$$

where $\widetilde{\alpha}$ and $\widetilde{v_{C}}$ are the perturbations from the steady state operating point. I was curious about difference between both of the models. So I have prepared a simulation in Scilab (free of charge variant of Matlab) with following values $R_b = 1.9, C = 2700\cdot 10^{-6}, v_{C_{0_e}} = 800, \alpha_{0_e} = 0.5$ and $\mathrm{d\_alpha} \sim \widetilde{\alpha}, \mathrm{d\_vC} \sim \widetilde{v_{C}}$.

[image]

I have done two runs of the simulation (black trace is the output/state of the nonlinear system, green trace is the output/state of the linearized system)

1. $\widetilde{\alpha} = 0.1$

[image]

2. $\widetilde{\alpha} = 0.2$

[image]

The results I have received were surprising for me. Because based on them it seems that increase in the deviation from the steady state operating point used for linearization results in increase of the interval where the linearized model follows the nonlinear one. I would say that I have done a mistake somewhere. May I ask you for help?

Comment: the equation is linear in the ODE meaning, just with non-constant coefficient: check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=v%27%5Bt%5D%3D-k*v%5Bt%5D*a%5Bt%5D&lang=es)

Comment: You did not perform the linearization at a steady state operating point, since at your choice for $(v_{C_{0_e}}, \alpha_{0_e})$ you don't have $d/dt\ v_C=0$. Either $v_{C_{0_e}}=0$ or $\alpha_{0_e}=0$.

Comment: @Joako I would argue against that interpretation of the ODE because $\alpha$ is an input to the system and hence unspecified until we select a concrete control law. By defining $\alpha$ as a general function of $t$ like you did in the Wolfram Alpha link, you made an assumption. However, I can select $\alpha=-1$ for example and I obtain a linear time invariant ODE. Or I select $\alpha=t$ then I get a linear timevarying ODE. Or I select $\alpha=v_c$ then I get a nonlinear ODE. So it depends I would say.

Comment: @SampleTime If you take $\alpha = v_c$ then $\alpha$ is not a control parameter anymore and your system  has a different specification (since $v_c$ is the unkown free variable to solve the ODE). The other cases, $\alpha$ time variable or constant got solved as the W-A formula.

Comment: @Joako Using state variables for feedback is perfectly valid and actually a very common thing to do in control engineering. If I take $\alpha=-1$ then $\alpha$ is gone from the equation as well and hence not a control parameter anymore. And yes, that means that for each choice of $\alpha$ you might end up with a system that has a different specification, that's the whole point. Also note that my comment addresses the *classification* of such ODEs, not how to solve them (which is a very different question).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen thank you very much for your reaction. I have worked on the same problem from another perspective [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772262/how-to-design-pi-controller-for-a-non-linear-dynamic-system). Do I understand correctly that in case I choose $$v_{C_{0_{e}}}=0$$ I will have $$\frac{\widetilde{v_C}(s)}{\widetilde{\alpha}(s)}=0$$  and in case I choose $$\alpha_{0_{e}}=0$$ I will have $$\frac{\widetilde{v_C}(s)}{\widetilde{\alpha}(s)}=-\frac{\frac{v_{C_{0}}}{R_b\cdot C}}{s}$$

Answer (score 1):

I will introduce an additional substitution with

$$\alpha(t) = -R_bC\dfrac{\dot{u}(t)}{u(t)}$$

As mentioned in the comments the system is a linear ODE.

$$\dfrac{dv_C}{v_C}=\dfrac{\dot{u}(t)}{u(t)}dt \implies \dfrac{dv_C}{v_C}=\dfrac{du(t)}{u(t)}$$
$$\ln v_C(t)-\ln v_C(t_0)=\ln u(t) - \ln u(t_0)$$
$$v_C(t) = \dfrac{v_C(t_0)}{u(t_0)}u(t)$$

As soon as you fix the desired trajectory for $v_C(t)$ you can determine $u(t)$. Using $\alpha(t) = -R_bC\dfrac{\dot{u}(t)}{u(t)}$ will give you ideal solution to the problem. But as we all know this will not work in real life due to imperfect dynamics or inaccurate parameter values. But I enjoyed the process of solving the problem :D.